# Using Springboot Mapping (RequestMapping, PathVariable, etc) on spring-boot-starter-jersey project with JAX-RS Mapping (@Path, @GET, etc)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs, spring-jersey

I'm adding a new set of features to a micro-service which I originally developed in Jersey (years ago) and later ported to springboot-jersey (a few less years ago).

Since then I got used to other frameworks and languages, so I want to:
1- Use Kotlin
2- Springboot's Web Annotations to perform the rest endpoints' mapping while maintaining support for JAX-RS' mapping annotations

The Kotlin part itself was "easy-peasy", all I needed was to add the kotlin runtime dependencies to the project's 'pom.xml' and create Kotlin classes.
However, when I created a simple endpoint using Springboot's mappings it didn't worked (HTTP call to the endpoint returns a HTTP 404 Status Code):

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/springboot/test")
class UnitController {

    @GetMapping
    fun getUnit() : String = "Test"
}
```

However if I use the JAX-RS mapping it works fine (HTTP call to the endpoint returns a HTTP 200 Status Code and the "Test" message):

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET
import javax.ws.rs.Path

@Path("/jersey/test")
class UnitController {

    @GET
    fun getUnit() : String = "Test"
}
```

Here's the project's pom.xml (the part that matter to the issue anyway):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jersey.version>2.28</jersey.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.72</kotlin.version>
        <springboot.version>2.2.7.RELEASE</springboot.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I've researched for some time and didn't found anything related to this matter.
Is my "hybrid" Springboot and JAX-RS mapping annotation approach even possible?

I'd most thankful if someone could please clarify this out for me...

EDIT:
I've forgot to mention that the 'UnitController' is registered under the JerseyConfig:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {

        register(UnitController.class);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify what type of problem occurred when you tried spring?

Comment: Sure @MinarMahmud. I received a 404 Not Found HTTP Response Status. I'll edited the original post to clarify this matter. Thank you :)

Comment: you can have jersey and spring boot endpoint, but why using same path?

Comment: @user7294900 I don't want the same endpoint. It was just a coincidence. I'll just update the question to make that clear. Thank you!